# Remove part of the name of multiple files

Tags: file-io

I have a bunch of files, the first few letters of which are all the same, eg:

```
VERindex.htm
VERstandard.css
VERfoo.bar
```

Is there an easy way to remove the VER from the beginning of all of the filenames? I'm using Windows 7. A CMD line solution would make me just as happy as a graphical one.

Comment: I am not sure but can easily be done in Java.

Answer (score 2):

You could try `rename VER*.* *.*` in the directory where your files are stored. I would test this out on a dummy file first in a directory that does not contain anything else.

**EDIT**: You might want to enclose those in quotes if your filenames have spaces in them. Then it would just be `rename "VER*.*" "*.*"`. Again, I would test this before running it on your important data.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work for me? if i do `rename VER*.* ABC*.*` then the files get renamed to ABC..., but if the number of characters before the `*.*` differs then I get unexpected results

Comment: Try `rename VER*.* *?.*` or `rename VER* *?` or `rename VER* *`. Sorry, I am not on a Windows machine so I cannot test these myself. [This document](http://superuser.com/questions/475874/how-does-the-windows-rename-command-interpret-wildcards) does a good job describing the command and how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

here's a vbscript version modified from [here](http://coderstalk.blogspot.com/2007/09/vbscript-to-replace-underscores-in.html) to only match VER at the beginning of the filename:

```
Dim sName
Dim fso
Dim fol

' create the filesystem object
Set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' get current folder
Set fol = fso.GetFolder("c:\temp")

' go thru each file in the folder
For Each fil In fol.Files
' check if the file name starts with VER
   If Left(fil.Name, 3) = "VER" Then
    ' strip ver
    sName = Replace(fil.Name, "VER", "")
    ' rename the file
    fil.Name = sName
   End If
Next

' echo the job is completed
WScript.Echo "Completed!"
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [rename](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/rename.mspx?mfr=true).

It's a command line utility; you should be able to specify wildcards to rename your files.